# spfx context undefined

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph

in my react component i  use msgraph but i get the message "cannot read property 'context' of undefined"
My code:

```
this.context.msGraphClientFactory
        .getClient()
        .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {        
          client
            .api('/me')
            .get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
            console.log(response);
            });
        })
```

I tried to pass the context from my webpart to the component but then i get the error "Cannot read property 'context' of undefined"

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is because the `msGraphClientFactory` is an object on the SPFx web part context and not the react component context.

You will need to pass the `msGraphClientFactory` object explicitly as a property to the React component.

In your SPFx webpart:

```
public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<ICustomWebPartProps> = React.createElement(
      CustomWebPart,
      {
        msGraphClientFactory: this.context.msGraphClientFactory,
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }
```

And then in your React component, you can reference that from the current component props object:

```
this.props.msGraphClientFactory
        .getClient()
        .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {        
          client
            .api('/me')
            .get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
            console.log(response);
            });
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it resolved my issue. Any reason why we have to explicitly pass this ?